# Error check for non-numerical data

Tags: c#, copy-paste, error-checking

I was hoping someone could help with an error check for my paste method. I would like to prevent pasting anything that is not a numeric value from clipboard into my textBox. The coding for pasting is listed below.

```
       private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                 // Determine if there is any text in the Clipboard to paste into the text box. 
                if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) == true)
                {
                    // Determine if any text is selected in the text box. 
                    if (textBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
                    {
                        // Ask user if they want to paste over currently selected text. 
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to paste over current selection?", "Cut Example", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
                            // Move selection to the point after the current selection and paste.
                            textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart + textBox1.SelectionLength;
                    } // end if
                } // Paste current text in Clipboard into text box.
                textBox1.Paste();
   } // end pasteToolStripMenuItem
```

Comment: Do you want to prevent users from pasting, or do you want users to be able to paste it but automatically remove non-numerical data?

Comment: right now you can paste anything you want into the textBox. I would like an error message to occur if you tried to paste "abc", so anything that is not a number

Comment: How about Ctrl+V?  How about the Paste command on the text box' context menu?  Don't write code like this.  Use the Validating event instead.

Comment: @HansPassant - sorry I dont quite follow what you mean? I just started reading up on C# 2 weeks ago :)

Comment: Does "numeric" include signs, decimal places, thousands separators?

Comment: @spender - yes it does. It's actually a very basic calculator. Thus why I do not want any letters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include `Currency symbols`, `decimal places`, `Thousand seperators` etc. `Int.Parse` is probably your best bet

```
    public bool IsValidNumber(string input)
    {
        int val = 0;
        return int.TryParse(input.Trim(), NumberStyles.Any, null, out val);
    }

"$100,000" = true
"100.002" = true
"1000,44j" = false
etc.
```

Comment: Updated to allow valid numeric symbols